# Are crops pollinated by bringing in bees still vegan?

Tags: is-it-vegan, bees

I had someone smugly tell me that I need to stop eating fruits and vegetables where bees have been brought in to pollinate them.

I've responded that I'm fine with plants being pollinated by bees, but it does make me wonder about the fate of those bees if they are also honey bees.

Is anything supported by 'brought in' bee pollination vegan?

Comment: I need to read that answer properly but yes I think this is a duplicate and I'll probably mark it as such once I've read the answers properly later, thanks for pointing it out (I obviously didn't search well enough).